# Nginx yii2 configuration

Tags: nginx, yii, centos

**Hi there!**

I'am trying to configure Nginx for 2 yii projects, **frontend** for users and **admin** for admins with only one domain (no sub domain). I need to configure it in a way such that **mydomain.com** should refer to **frontend** and **mydomain.com/admin** to **admin**. The problem is I'am being able to configure only one of them at a time, meaning I can use frontend or admin not both of them.

*What I have tried*

**front.conf**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name api.maim.experiments.uz;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate_key privkey.pem;
    ssl_certificate     fullchain.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;

    set $host_path "/home/itschool/inha_dev/frontend";   

    server_name  api.maim.experiments.uz;
    root        $host_path/web;

    set $yii_bootstrap "index.php";

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/itschool-access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/itschool-error.log;

    location / {
        index index.html $yii_bootstrap;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ ^/(protected|framework|themes/\w+/views) {
        deny  all;
    }

    location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

        set $fsn /index.php;
           if (-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name){
               set $fsn $fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9002;

        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fsn;
    }

    location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git) {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

**back.conf**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name api.maim.experiments.uz;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate_key privkey.pem;
    ssl_certificate     fullchain.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;

    set $host_path "/home/itschool/inha_dev/backend";   

    server_name  api.maim.experiments.uz;
    root        $host_path/web;

    set $yii_bootstrap "index.php";

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/itschool-access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/itschool-error.log;


    location ^~ /admin {
        alias /home/itschool/inha_dev/backend/web;

        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /admin/index.php last; }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }

            include        fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9002;
        }
    }

    location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git) {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

I found some questions with answers but they didn't work for me, please help.

Comment: Why don't you use sub domain for this ??

Comment: I would checkout [Yii2 Single Domain Apache and Nginx](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/799/yii2-app-advanced-on-single-domain-apache-nginx).

Answer (score 4):

I have recently use similar configuration to support web application / mobile application and admin panel on single domain

I hope this could help you out. Below is the configuration

```
server {
        listen 80;

        set $root /var/www/html/application;

        #here we go
        #if backend not found in url then set root url
        if ($uri !~ "^(.*)/(backend)(.*)") {
            set $root /var/www/html/application/frontend/web;
        }

        # when request is coming from mobile then display mobile site
        # you don't need this one, I just written in order to explain the mobile application navigation.
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos") {
            set $root /var/www/html/application/mobile/web;
        }

        root $root;

        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name your_domain;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        location / {
            index  index.html index.php;
            if (!-e $request_filename){
                rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?r=$1 last;
            }
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Also have a look in official document of **Yii2 to setup yii2-app-advanced on single domain (Apache, Nginx)**.
[CLICK HERE](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/799/yii2-app-advanced-on-single-domain-apache-nginx)

One more thing that you need to know is if you want to change **backend/web** to **admin** then you also have to made some changes in Yii2 application.

Answer (score 3):

One domain will lead all requests to one IP (server). Nginx will use the first `server` block matching server_name https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html so you need to put all configuration on one file and use `location` to separate them.
You can move `location ^~ /admin` at the beginning of the `front.conf` locations and play with roots;
Or you can create a proxying config file that will contain just a little.
Something like that

```
location /admin {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
}
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8002;
}
```

Using the latter one you should change front & back configs to listen to other ports. Also, an SSL certificate was given for a domain, not URL. So you can use it only in the proxying config.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow some of the key instructions from option 1 of [Yii2 Single Domain Apache and Nginx](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/799/yii2-app-advanced-on-single-domain-apache-nginx) you should be able to accomplish what you want.

#### Per the referenced link, Option 1:

Assuming Linux OS

```
cd /path/to/project/frontend/web
ln -s ../../backend/web backend
```

and set your nginx file

```
server {
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    listen 80; ## listen for ipv4
    #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    server_name api.maim.experiments.uz;
    root        /home/itschool/inha_dev/frontend/web;
    index       index.php;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/itschool-access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/itschool-error.log;

    location / {
        # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # uncomment to avoid processing of calls to non-existing static files by Yii
    #location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
    #    try_files $uri =404;
    #}
    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # deny accessing php files for the /assets directory
    location ~ ^/assets/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location ~* /\. {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

#### Not: See below link for the Option-2, if the above does not work:

[Yii2 Single Domain Apache and Nginx](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/799/yii2-app-advanced-on-single-domain-apache-nginx)